# PHP configuration on .NET server - URL redirect

Tags: php, .net, url-rewriting, umbraco, forwarding

I have a server with a blog and the configuration right now is a big hot mess.

It's a .NET server running umbraco and the blog is hosted with wordpress within that.
As you can imagine the web.config of umbraco seems to override the PHP settings.

What I want is the blog which is "www.mydomain.com/blog" to be accessed from "blog.mydomain.com".
I've added an A record on blog.mydomain.com and waiting to see if that'll work, but I'm not sure if I also need some 301 redirect in place?

More importantly all the blog links crash because mydomain/blog/ doesn't go to index.php
(Umbraco makes default.aspx the default page even if index.php is listed as default on IIS).

Is there a rewrite rule that will make all empty slashes within the blog folder to default to index.php?

I found this is a bit promising but will only work on the parent folder:
I need something that will work on all subfolders of blog

```
<urlrewritingnet xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>
<add name="gotoindex"
               redirect="Domain"
               ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite"
               virtualUrl="http://mysitename/"
               redirectMode="Permanent"
               destinationUrl="http://mysitename/index.php" />
        </rewrites>
</urlrewritingnet>
```

Also I want the query string preserved.
Currently the links look like this: http://mydomain.com/blog/?m=201208 
which I would ideally want forwarded to http://mydomain.com/blog/index.php?m=201208

Any help is very appreciated.
Really lost here!! Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using a restful look like http://mydomain.com/blog/201208 or for this case (guessing the m stays for year/month) http://mydomain.com/blog/date/2012/08)

Comment: The query string works fine, what I want is to have index.php instead of default.aspx as a default page.
I don't think changing the format of the query string will help.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved it.

The key was to do this:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/, /blog/" />
```

By adding an exception to the web.config, blog folder was no longer bound the umbraco configuration and the IIS settings for PHP started working!

Also this rule also fixed the redirect from blog.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/blog

Add this key to UrlRewriting.config

```
<add name="blogfix" virtualUrl="^http\://blog.mydomain.co.uk/(.*)"
                    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
                    destinationUrl="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/blog/$1"
                    redirect="Domain"
                    redirectMode="Permanent"
                    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread but this saved me hours of head scratching, so thank's for this :)

Comment: Does this work with paths such as `domain.com/index.php/*`?